# xlrd error when importing xlrd using visual studio code on mac

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm running visual studio code on mac and running python 3.0.  I installed the xlrd package using pip install xlrd.  When I try to import xlrd my code crashed saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which IDE would you recommend? @ChootsMagoots

Comment: I just use a raw text editor and then `python [filename]` in the terminal

Comment: C'mon @user9504629 this is bush league sh*t. The xlrd w0bs1te https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd sez: "Pure Python (2.7, 3.4+)."

Comment: @bernie I'm impressed you managed to spell the link correctly

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0tMH-fZ-ls

Comment: after this, learn how `python -i [filename]` works, and then learn what `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` does